# How to visualize affine transformed data in Python

Tags: qgis, python, geotiff-tiff, visualisation, affine-transformation

I have Mavic 2 pro drone image, and try to apply georeferencing this JPG data.

With the help of VerticalPhotoPlacer code,

I first generate JGW file, then convert JPG data to GeoTIFF data.The code is mentioned below.

======================================================

```
image_transformation = Affine(a=a_,b=b_,d=d_,e=e_,c=c_,f=f_)

imagepath_geotiff = os.path.join(geotiffs_root_path, image_name + ".tif")
with rasterio.open(
        imagepath_geotiff,'w',driver='GTiff',
        height=original_image.height,
        width=original_image.width,
        count=len(original_image.indexes),dtype='uint8',
        crs="epsg:4326") as georeferenced_image:
    georeferenced_image.write(img)
```

======================================================

Then, I try to visualize affine transformed GeoTIFF data in Python.

However, the visualization result is not what I expected.
(the result is not transformed...)

[image]

Meanwhile, the expected result appears in QGIS..

[image]

Is there any method to visualize photo like QGIS in Python?

I think that the metadata of GeoTIFF changed..especially the image height and width.

[image]

I desire to visualize same as QGIS via python script.

Comment: Code should always be placed in Questions as text, so it is legible on all devices and copyable without transcription pain. Please [Edit] the Question.